# How to repair wooden garage wall sitting 2 feet below grade?

Tags: repair, garage, water-damage

I'm stopping by to see what people think might be the solution to the previous owner's "solution". I've got a garage with wooden walls that is butted directly up against an area of yard graded 2.5 feet higher than the garage floor. That patch of yard is contained with a retaining wall. We knew something was up after the first rainstorm and watched a flood of water pour in through the floor molding on the side that touches the retaining wall. I was advised to open up the drywall to get a decent look inside, and now we know that it's been rotting for years. Since we're not able to regrade the yard outside, does it make sense to replace the portion of wall/siding with a sealed/tarred cinderblock wall, and then reinstall the siding onto the shortened/replaced studs? I've seen similar posts that have recommendations featuring all-wood solutions, even when below-grade.

[image: Rotted wall/framing]  [image: Exterior/retaining wall showing grade differenceI]

Comment: A concrete or cement block wall above ground will probably be the best solution for a long(life time) fix.  Since it is a load bearing wall, an engineer might be a good idea to design it.  The retaining wall adds complexity to the solution.

Comment: I would continue the retaining wall across the width of the garage. Leave a space between the retaining wall and the wood wall allowing water to escape.

Comment: The old joke in carpenter school was that pressure treated foundations (a short-lived trend, thankfully) were the basis of a composting house. So, yes: concrete below grade.

Comment: Wait, beyond the wall where it looks to end near the gutter—is the earth filled up against the siding?

Comment: @Huesmann : yes, that's exactly what you're looking at. The earth is filled in directly against the wooden, painted siding.

Comment: I'm intrigued by @r13 's suggestion of extending the retaining wall -- would it make sense to build the drainage into this addition? For the sake of future maintenance, as others pointed out, maybe a combination of concrete below grade plus the gap created by extending the wall along the garage?

Comment: @NW.v02Beta The wooden wall shall be erected on a solid foundation, concrete, or masonry, which is a few inches above the exposed grade (see pic). Then you shall provide a trench between the foundation and the retaining wall. With a proper slope, the water will drain regardless of the base material, concrete base will help to prevent dirt from washing off though.

Comment: @NW.v02Beta so you have soil and the water it's holding against the wood siding.  A recipe for rot.  Does this setup run along the entire garage wall?

Comment: @Huesmann It's one of the most careless "additions" I've ever seen. It runs all the way along that wall, and even wraps around it slightly as the grade slopes down more gradually in the back yard.

Comment: @r13 Makes total sense, thanks for the clarification. Likely opting to put in a narrow concrete path to ensure access to the entire wall for maintenance purposes. Anything is better than what's there now, though!!

Comment: Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Is what we see on the inside the backs of the siding planks, or do you have another layer of wood inside the siding?

Comment: @Huesmann Those are siding planks, the only thing holding back the dirt. Higher up, there's grass beginning to grow through.

Comment: Wow, even more ghetto than I thought.  Might be better to excavate it all, build a sidewalk at grade, and a retaining wall to the outside of the sidewalk (sidewalk cross slope should drain towards retaining wall).

Answer (score 2):

You can go cinder/concrete block or poured concrete as you suggest, or you can use suitably treated wood (rated for ground contact, not merely "pressure treated") as is used for all-wooden foundations - as you prefer.

In *either* case, you should install drainage to remove water outside the wall when you have access, because even a "waterproofed" wall works a lot better when it's not fighting pressure trying to force water in.

Comment: Drainage is basically the top priority (outside of basic structural stability), I agree. Would your go-to in this situation be something along the lines of a french drain that links up to the existing gutter?